# ROS: is it possible to install it for RedHat 7

Tags: ros

Someone told me that the [ros](http://ros.org) was a good stuff. But my system is RedHat 7. It seems that the ros is not suitable for my system?

Did anyone install it under the RedHat 7 successfully?

Comment: Your question is probably going to be closed, as doing a poll/surveying is rather off topic. see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think it is easiest to use Ubuntu, as this is the officially supported platform. Maybe you can run Ubuntu in a virtual machine?

Comment: @nos     ok  thx for what you link.

Comment: @luator    for now, we have no such a plan.

Comment: How is this a programming related question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to compile ROS from source, it should definitely be possible. Follow the instructions on: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source and stay away from Ubuntu-isms replacing them with corresponding RedHat actions. There are subsections in the instructions that explain how to do things in Fedora.